# $\text{Show } \{(x,y):xy=0\}$ is path connected

Tags: general-topology

> **Def.(path-connected)**
>
> A set $S⊆\mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected if, for every pair of points $x$ and $y$ in $S$,
> $∃$ continuous $γ:[0,1]→S$, such that $γ(0)=x$, and $γ(1)=y$.

$\text{Show } \{(x,y):xy=0\}$ is path connected

$$S:=\{(x,y):xy=0\}$$

$$=\{(x,y):x=0\vee y=0\}$$

Let $p=(p_1,p_2),q=(q_1,q_2)\in S$

I want to constract some continuous $\gamma:[0,1]\cap\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that $\gamma(0)=(p_1,p_2)$ and $\gamma(1)=(q_1,q_2)$

The only function I can think about is $\gamma(t)=qt+p(1-t)$ which will output some convex combinations of $p,q$, but it isn't continuous over $S$

How do I make that function keep 'walking' on $S?$

Thanks for your help.

---

Update:

Take this would work, I think

$$\gamma(t)= \left\{\begin{array}{l}2p\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right),t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]\\2q\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right),t\in(\frac{1}{2},1]\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Your convex path will work if one of your points is $(0,0)$, now just paste the paths together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $\{(x,y):xy = 0\}$ is exactly the union of $x$-axis and $y$-axis. Thus, for any two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ in the set, you may walk $P_1$ to $(0,0)$ and then to $P_2$. This will be a path from $P_1$ to $P_2$.

Comment: Consider $\gamma_1:[0,1/2]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\gamma_1(t) = (1/2-t)P_1$ and $\gamma_2:[1/2,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\gamma_2(t) = 2(t-1/2)P_2$. Then patch them together.